# Social Account Access to MyAccess Portal

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

We used to be able to have social accounts request access packages by signing in at myaccess.microsoft.com. Now, we get an error that says you can not sign in with a personal account. Why is this the case since it remains possible to create a domain like gmail.com or outlook.com as a connected organization in Entitlement Management?
Also, after landing on the myaccess portal and expanding an access package that a user has been approved for to view its resources, it used to be able for example, to open a SharePoint site or an application directly from this view by simply clicking on the resource or clicking an open Now that ability has been removing leaving us to have to send links tot he resource to users. This degrades experience substantially. Can we have this ability returned?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the type of personal account in your portal, and if ***guest***, you cannot log in `myaccess.onmicrosoft.com` , if created in the portal or of type ***member***, it is accessible.

This is the relevant [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-request-access).

> Sign in to the My Access portal.
>
> Be sure you use your organizational (work or school) account. If
> you're unsure, check with your project or business manager.

I invited my personal account (user type) to test if I login directly `myaccess.onmicrosoft.com`.And the following screenshots do report errors.
[image]

Comment: Actually, the whole point of allowing Entitlement Management access packages to be assignable to external users is to support guest accounts and this works today. The issue is when the guest account is a social (and hence MSA) vs. a work or school account. It used to work for both, and still does. But it seems that for social guest accounts, something has recently changed.

Comment: Any help around this will be appreciated.